# ¿Como conectar a una Base de datos MongoDB mediante PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

Hola alguien sabe como me puedo conectar a la base de datos MongoDB? ya he instalado los .Dll necesarios junto con el composer y a la hora de querer conectar me sale un error de que la clase de MongoClient no esta definida.

```
require_once "variables.php";

use MongoDB;
use MongoDB\Command;
use MongoDB\Exception;

$a = new MongoClient();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

siendo que las clases de mongo me salen en el autocompletador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui estan los archivos de composer:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y aqui esta el php info
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe porque no me deja usar las clases de Mongo?

Comment: Tu código debe ir como texto, para poder visualizar como importas la clase al archivo donde planeas usarla

Comment: @BetaM listo, no tengo mucho en el codigo ya que estoy investigando porque me sale ese error

Comment: Esta instancia `.... = new MongoClient` ocupa la clase `MongoClient` pero ¿dicha clase de dónde proviene?

Comment: @BetaM proviene del archivo php_mongodb.dll que esta en la carpeta de ext de php

Comment: A lo que voy tratas de generar una instancia pero ¿no deberías estar haciendo un `require............`  o un `use.....` (*según sea el caso que cargues las clases*) del archivo que la contiene?

Comment: @BetaM segun eso no se necesita eso, ya le intente poner Use MongoClient y no funciona

Comment: Lo único que se me ocurre comentar es ¿luego de incluir las DDL correspondientes reiniciaste el servidor?

Comment: @BetaM si, intente reiniciarlo y no lo reconoce, pero si te fijas en la imagen del php info que esta en la publicación sale que esta correctamente instalado

Comment: Según [el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mongoclient.php)  **`MongoClient` es obsoleta**. Se recomienda usar en su lugar [`MongoDB\Driver\Manager`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.mongodb-driver-manager.php). Como verás, la conexión es bastante sencilla.

Comment: @BetaM ya me funciono amigo con el MongoDB\Driver\Mananger pero ahora resulto otro problema lo que pasa es que en el IDE me sale que esa clase no existe pero cuando lo ejecuto en el navegador no salen excepciones y si funciona la clase, como puedo evitar que el IDE me marque ese error?